# Tool requirements for moving rocker arms?

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, tools, valve, katana

1994 Suzuki Katana 600.  Manual says to pry the rocker arm aside "using a suitable tool" to get at the valve shims (unlike some other bikes where the procedure is to remove the camshafts).

What would make a suitable tool here?  What should I be concerned about?

Is just any old pry tool fine or should I be looking for something with a special tip or some other feature to avoid possibly doing some damage in the process?

Comment: How strong are the springs between the rockers or rocker to support? Perhaps something just sufficient to hold them clear. Some workshop manuals will give a picture and useful dimensions shown so you can make one.

Comment: @SolarMike Well, not really sure...  I do own a plastic prybar, so perhaps I'll start there and see what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My plastic prybar worked well and left no marks.  For reference it's an OTC 2487 plastic "Combination Wedge and Pry tool".